# confronting other orgs using public ip's internally

Tags: networking, ip

A company that we deal with has their internal network numbered with 120.1.254.0/24, specifically a mail server. That IP range belongs in China, causing all of their mail to be flagged as suspicious by our SPAM filter.

I found this rant about using other people's IP's on your network: http://mellowd.co.uk/ccie/?p=886

Do you know of any better articles/rants about this subject? This one is not convincing enough for me.

Comment: If they aren't convinced of the stupidity of their ways by their email being classified as Chinese spam, I don't think any article or rant is going to do a better job at convincing them.

Comment: This type of behavior is very common, even among large hardware vendors who should know better. As an example, Compellent (now owned by by Dell) uses a DoD netblock for the heartbeat circuit between SAN head units. I tried to get someone in their support org to see that this is a bad thing to do, but no one seemed to understand the problem.

Comment: For some organisations this can be a historical issue.  IP networks were growing in popularity before businesses thought they'd be exposing internal systems to the Internet.  There may well be a lot of reasons why it's non-trivial to reverse old decisions, and it comes down to business cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a reason to present to them - the incorrect spam flagging.

Comment: The reply will likely be: "Oh, can't you whitelist that range?" since it's easier to impose costly time and effort on someone else than fix the problem correctly.

Comment: Then you say "No, because those IPs aren't unique, because you're breaking the Internet, you jackass." Suitably edited for business purposes, of course.